# Unexpected answer in c++

Tags: c++, function, long-double

i wrote this code in c++. i expect 4932.08 for the answer(calculated by calculator)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    long double a;
    a = LDBL_MAX;
    cout << "log10(" << a << ") = " << log10(a);    
}
```

sizeof(a) = 16 Bytes on my computer

instead of getting the correct answer, the output was *inf*. what is the problem? is it about the sizeof data log10 can get? what should i do to get correct answer?

I run this code with DEV and g++ (MinGW) by CMD. results are interesting.

DEV: inf

MinGW: 4932.08

sizeof(a):

dev: 16

MinGW: 12

why???

thank you

Comment: What does `log10l` do? What is `sizeof(long double)` on your platform?

Comment: What is the *actual* output? I think I know the answer, but am not going to write it out until I know for sure.

Comment: @Bathsheba What is unclear about `inf printed as the answer`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a bug in the standard library implementation.

Comment: @eerorika: inf is not printed as the answer. Where is "log10" for example? I'm trying to establish if the issue is in the `log10` call (it probably is due to the incorrect headers - the long double overload does not have to be reachable via math.h), or in the ostream overload to long double. Really, I don't understand why you need me to state this - it ought to be obvious to you.

Comment: Now your edit has ruined the question. If you're expecting 372.111571972 then long double and double are the same on your platform.

Comment: @Bathsheba that number was what i expected. i calculated by calculator.

Comment: @Bathsheba as i said in last edit it is 16 bytes. sorry. first time in this site. i just learning c++

Comment: @Bathsheba the actual output is *inf*

Comment: @eerorika really? is it a bug?

Comment: @Saman Correct result for logarithm of non-infinite input is not infinity. So yes, as far as I can tell, this is a bug.

Comment: what compiler do you use? on gcc9.3.0 output of this code is _log10(1.18973e+4932) = 4932.08_

Comment: @EugeneAfanasyev you right, but the problem is variable sizeof. why in MinGW the size is different as DEV?